# (iphone) how accurate can corelocation become indoor?

Tags: iphone, core-location

I've read core location is not accurate when in indoor(no clear view of sky) with 3gs or wifi.

I wonder how inaccurate it is, would it be able to achieve , eg) 100m 500m accuracy?
Would it be impossible to get no more accurate than 2000m accurary?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the building you are in. In my tests it achieved from 65m to 2000m accuracy so it wasn't really reliable indoors.

If the buildings have glass ceilings then the accuracy could be better than 100m.

If you want to use it for inside buildings guiding you should find other solutions.